# How to Send a file with keeping its extension through a python socket?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to send one file which is txt file through a python socket. I want the txt file which is received by the client keeps its extension which is txt.

Here is my server's side:

```
import socket                  

port = 50000                   
s = socket.socket()             
host = "localhost"   
s.bind((host, port))           
s.listen(5)                     

print 'Server listening....'


while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()     
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print('Server received', repr(data))

    filename='file.txt' 
    f = open(filename,'rb')

    while (f):
       conn.send(filename)

    f.close()

    print('Done sending')
    conn.close()
```

Here is my client's side:

```
import socket                   # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()             # Create a socket object
host = "localhost"  #Ip address that the TCPServer  is there
port = 50000                     # Reserve a port for your service every new transfer wants a new port or you must wait.

s.connect((host, port))
s.send("Hello server!")

while True:
    print('receiving the file...')
    data = s.recv()
    if not data:
        break

print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

All I found online is either modifying this file or sending a text in that file.

Comment: The socket is just a pipe: on one side, you feed it with data read from the file, which comes out on the other side of the pipe. Now, you control the data. The code you show here *only sends the content of the file*. What you want is to also communicate the filename to the receiving side. Now, I suggest you look at how HTTP POST achieves that, or how the FTP protocol works. You can get creative yourself, after all you control the pipe, client and server. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your server code just sends the filename over and over again in an infinite loop. Your client code doesn't do anything with the data sent by the server but prints "receiving the file..." over and over again. Why?

Comment: @JamesKPolk That's right! It's always an infinite loop.

Comment: @sal I understand. My concern is there anyway to reimplement the code in order to send the file itself, not its content? Well, I have used _WGET_ and _CURL_ in order to send a file in this post (https://serverfault.com/questions/971942/unable-to-download-file-using-wget-on-aws-instance-enabled-sr) but it did not work. I thought if I try python socket would help to send the file as an alternative way.

Comment: I've read your serverfault post: I'd involve Cisco support for that. Once they help you fix wget/curl, then you wouldn't need to reimplement a file transfer protocol on your own. If you just need to fix what you have up there, you'd need to remove the `while True` from the sender (you only need to send the file once), and make sure the client actually writes the received data to a file. As for the filename, you would need to implement a signalling protocol, so that you can distinguish what is Commands (i.e. the-next-bytes-are-the-filename) and Data (i.e. the-next-bytes-are-the-file-content).

Comment: And of course, make sure the sender sends the data inside the file, not just the filename

Comment: @sal you were right! it turns out that were an issue with *MTU* value! Is there any way to send the file like partly? I mean send part of the file until the highest *MTU* value then make a pause/sleep for couple of seconds till the end of file?

Comment: I am a little rusty on this topic, but I think your best bet is to manually check (and set) the MTU on the interfaces of the server and client, so as to match the MTU of the network, assuming it's less than 1500. But that's really an optimization, the network would (or should) be able to handle fragmentation on its own. Maybe somebody else can pitch their expertise on this :-)